# Код с js в codepen и jsdin работает, а в моем редакторе sublime не работает?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. 
Скопировала код с js простого видеоплейера из codepen к себе в редактор. 
В codepen код работает, в jsbin тоже, а у меня при просмотре в  браузере нет.
 Я только учусь и не понимаю почему...

```js
(function() {
  var v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
  for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
    var p = document.createElement("div");
    p.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
    p.onclick = labnolIframe;
    v[n].appendChild(p);
  }
})();

function labnolThumb(id) {
  return '<img class="youtube-thumb" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + id + '/hqdefault.jpg"><div class="play-button"></div>';
}

function labnolIframe() {
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.setAttribute("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.parentNode.dataset.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=2&border=0&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");
  iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
  iframe.setAttribute("id", "youtube-iframe");
  this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #232323;
}

.youtube-container {
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #17254A;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 90px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-filter: opacity(92%);
  filter: opacity(92%);
}

.youtube-player {
  display: block;
  background-color: #242424;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

img.youtube-thumb {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  margin: -9.25% auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: auto
}

div.play-button {
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -36px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/TxzC70f.png") no-repeat;
}

#youtube-iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="youtube-container">
  <div class="youtube-player" data-id="NAwtm4baDeE"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: хоспаде 
дайте в коммент ссылку на codepen, может подскажу, пока вопрос не заминусовали

Comment: Добавьте свой [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://codepen.io/Devourz/pen/XdwGxV

Comment: Пытаюсь запустить у себя в редакторе этот код

Comment: или в вот  ссылка на более простой код (без css) в jsbin: https://output.jsbin.com/qiyirem/1

Answer (score 1):

Код будет работать если HTML поместить в html файл, например, в index.html и обернуть в полноценную html страницу:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <style>
body {
  background: #232323;
}

.youtube-container {
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #17254A;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 90px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-filter: opacity(92%);
  filter: opacity(92%);
}

.youtube-player {
  display: block;
  background-color: #242424;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

img.youtube-thumb {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  margin: -9.25% auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: auto
}
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="youtube-container">
          <div class="youtube-player" data-id="NAwtm4baDeE"></div>
      </div>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function() {
  var v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
  for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
    var p = document.createElement("div");
    p.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
    p.onclick = labnolIframe;
    v[n].appendChild(p);
  }
})();

function labnolThumb(id) {
  return '<img class="youtube-thumb" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + id + '/hqdefault.jpg"><div class="play-button"></div>';
}

function labnolIframe() {
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.parentNode.dataset.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=2&border=0&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");
  iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
  iframe.setAttribute("id", "youtube-iframe");
  this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}
       </script>
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Лучше, конечно, по разным CSS и JS файлам разнести, но для новичка нужно начать с этого.

Comment: Все сделала: 1) создала в редакторе ()

Comment: Все сделала: 1) создала в редакторе (sublime text 3) файл index.html; 2) всавила код во все необходимые теги (<!DOCTYPE html>, <html>, <head>, <body>, <script>); 3) сохранила и запустила просмотр в браузере .... и ... не работает, в jsbin работает, а у меня нет ((((( голову сломала, почему?.. Вот мой код:

Comment: https://jsbin.com/qiyirem/edit?html,output                                                                         Это код который я ввожу в своем редакторе и он (код) у меня в браузере не работает... (( не понимаю почему

Comment: я в стопоре... залила данный код к себе на openserver и оттуда попробовала запустить. Все получилось, работает.... А пытаюсь запустить в редакторе sublime , ниччего не работает... обьясните мне пожалуйста, что не так???

Comment: Поправил. Проблема в том, что в URL-ы начинались с //, это значит относительно текущего протокола. В случае если просто html файл открываете, получается что ищется ссылка file://www.youtube.com. Вобщем не ставьте // в начале URL лучше, это нужно делать осознанно, например чтобы сохранить вызов http в https

Comment: Большое спасибо, наконец то поняла.))))))))))))))) Ура!!!